# Composer: extra (not necessary) dependencies installed

Tags: php, composer-php

Basic question about composer. I would like to test composer and install jquery with it.
I created a composer.json file inside a project subfolder (project_root/test).

```
{
    "require": {
        "components/jquery": "^1.11.2"
    }
}
```

Then I opened command prompt (with path = 'project_root/test' = same folder of composer.json) and executed:

```
composer install
```

Problem: composer installs NOT ONLY jquery but also symfony and some other stuff.

It's true that I have a symfony project in another folder (totally different folder with different path) which is "under composer"... it seems that composer is "mixing" the two projects.
Any ideas?

P.s. I installed composer with the windows installer (I think it's called global install)

Comment: My personal preference is to use `composer` for server-side stuff and `bower`  (http://bower.io/) for client-side libraries. It's basically the same syntax, but meant for front-end.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice!! I've already read the documentation about bower, but since I had composer already installed I decided to try this first. I will definitely try bower next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking on Packagist, it seems that the version of `components/jquery` you want to install requires another package (`robloach/component-installer`), which then requires some other things, which require more things, etc.  Eventually, it looks like you end up getting to symphony.

Composer is recursive in that it installs not just the things your package requires, but anything that those things require, etc.  This is why you are getting symphony.

Comment: Side note: `components/jquery` after 2.0 no longer has any requirements, so you might consider upgrading.

Comment: I'm going to test this right now... if I use jquery 2.0 and still get symfony... then there is actually an error

Comment: @IgorCarmagna Sorry I lied just a bit: you have to go up to 2.1.3 in order to drop the dependency.

Comment: Just tested it... it works!! I used version 2.1.3. Specifically this is the line "components/jquery": "^2.1.3".

Comment: Anyway, it's really strange... I suppose there is actually a reason behind this behaviour. Anyone knows why jquery < 2.1.3 also install symfony (with composer)?